# Rename a sequence of variable names in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 5 columns in a data frame and I would like to rename the variable names as Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5.

My current approach is not very convenient:

```
names(mydata)[1:10] <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5")
```

Is there a better way so that when I have 100 variables, I don't have to type all 100 names?

Answer (score 13):

```
names(mydata)[1:100] <- paste("Var", 1:100, sep="")
```

Comment: Thank you DWin, for your reply. Very helpful!

Comment: better still is `paste0("Var", 1:100)` with less typing (as of R 2.15)

Comment: They're BOTH faster than what I've been doing. God bless SO.

Answer (score 9):

The `sprintf` function would be ideal for this:

```
names(mydata)[1:100] <- sprintf("Var%d", 1:100)
```

or

```
names(mydata)[1:100] <- sprintf("Var%03d", 1:100)
```

Depending on if you want names like "Var1","Var2",... or "Var001","Var002", ...

Comment: For what it's worth, yours is better than mine.